# Variable Declaration and Initialization in Robot Framework within a Test Cases block

Tags: robotframework

I tried to Declare and Initialize a variable in Robot Framework using Selenium platform. But I'm getting an **Error** **`Keyword name cannot be empty.`**

I tried the following code

**Integer**:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    ${item}       ${0}  # ${}
```

**Boolean**:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 2
    ${item}    ${true}    #${}
```

**String**:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 3
    ${item}    Stackoverflow
```

Kindly assist me how to declare and initialize a variable within a **Test Cases** block in Robot Framework.

> Reply for @Goralight

I'm getting an error

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use the `Set Variable` Keyword to assign values to Variables outside the Variable Header:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    ${item}    Set Variable    ${0}    #${}

    ${item}    Set Variable    ${true}    #${}

    ${item}    Set Variable    Stackoverflow
```

The above assigns the variable you have given in your test cases to the correct value. (This will overwrite `${item}` every time of course however) But this will assign the value, to the var `${item}`.

Read the Docs about it [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable)

Any questions please ask :)

Comment: I'm getting an error. Kindly refer the question, I attached the screen shot of an error.

Comment: I cant see images.. can you post the error instead please?

Comment: `${item}    Set Variable    ${0}    #${}` => **`Variable definition not found`** in `${0}`

Comment: For me it sets it to `0`. Its because you haven't set the Variable `${0}` to anything yet. Have you tried running it and seeing what happens? for me it passes fine. You need to give `${0}` a value before you can use it, so use the same method as the answer or assign it in the variable header

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan After installing Intelibot on my Pycharm IDE, I see the error too. But it doesn't stop me from passing the test as it sets the value of the variable to 0 by default. Was you expecting `${0}` to do something else?

Comment: Instead of `${0}` I'm using plain `0` - Now its working.

Comment: Great! Glad to help :)

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan: look very closely at the error. It's not telling you that `${0}` doesn't exist, it's telling you `${0} #${}` doesn't exist. It looks like you only have a single space between `${0}` and `#${}` so it thinks that whole group of characters is a single variable.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan I got it too within Pycharm and know what you are on about. But its because the Variable `${0}` has no value. You haven't gave it anything so when you run it, it will default to `0`. Assign `${0}` a value first and then try it.

Comment: @Goralight - it showing the same `Variable definition not found` - which is exactly same as I posted as a reply for your answer.

Comment: Ok try this then `${0} | Set Variable | someValue` and then try and use `${0}` later down

Comment: I defined one variable using "Set Variable " keyword under the Test_00. So I just wanna to know is scope of a variable limit to only particular testcase ?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the following is a more readable way to do it:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1

    ${item} =    Set Variable    ${0}            #${}

    ${item} =    Set Variable    ${true}         #${}

    ${item} =    Set Variable    Stackoverflow
```

You will get an error if you do the following:

```
    ${item} =   Stackoverflow
```

The reason is that this assignment is expecting a keyword `Stackoverflow` on right hand side.

Here is a working example of such assignment.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    ${item} =    Get My Value
    Log          ${item}

*** Keywords ***
Get My Value
    ${my text} =    Set Variable    Stackoverflow
    [return]        ${my text}
```